# Imitating NUnit Test Adapter feature that lists NUnit test case methods in Visual Studio on a Simple Test Harness Webpage

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, nunit, automated-tests, ui-testing

Here are the details of my Development Environment:

•Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 4

•Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m

•Selenium Chrome Driver Win 32 2.12

•Windows 7 Professional with 32-bit Operating System

•NUnit 2.6.3

One of our Customers wanted us to create Test Harness Webpages that we can use to test various UI components of our web application.

The Test Harness should be Simple Webpage where we can test the ViewPanel of the web application or the Footer for the Web application.

It's the components like the ViewPanel or the footer that could be complex, but the Test Harness WebPage should be simple.

Without adding too much complexity, I was wondering if there was a way to list out NUnit test case methods in a Test Harness Webpage.

Basically, I want to imitate the feature of the  NUnit Test Adapter.  Visual Studio 2012 will interact with the NUnit Test Adapter to discover tests and a list of them will be shown in the Unit Test Explorer of Visual Studio.

Here is how the NUnit test case methods are listed in Visual Studio:

[image]

So, I just want to imitate the said feature on the Test Harness WebPage so that our testers/developers can just click on a test case method listed in the Test Harness WebPage in order to make it run.

If it takes too much time, and if it's too complex then I would rather leave this feature out.  Moreover, if it's too complex, then that would be bad too because our Customer has requested that the Test Harness Webpage be kept as Simple as possible.  Is the aforementioned feature easy to implement, and simple?